# SSIS Rely on server storage and roles for access control strange behavior

Tags: ssis

I have created an SSIS package and saved a copy as:

Package Location : SQLServer
Server: Local
Authentication Type: SQL Server Authentication
Username: Created a local SQL account here
Protection level: Rely on server storage and roles for access control

This package is automatically ran under the SQL agent under a proxy account. If I stay logged into the windows server as this proxy account, the job runs fine. If I log out, the job never finishes and is stuck in the "running" state. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using mapped drives in your SSIS? USe UNC's instead. Perhaps you should post a summary of what your package does.

Comment: The SSIS package does not use a Map drive. It basically fires off a batch file that runs a .exe(runs a bunch of calculations). These calculations are imported into SQL and exported into a text file. This file is then ftp to a vendor of ours.

Comment: You need to use the package log to work out where it is stuck. Also use task manager to work out whether your EXE has been spawned or not. What does your EXE do? Does it connect to anything or pick up any files?